# How to develop an application for the Sony DSC RX100-M3 camera

Tags: camera, sony

I have the RX100-M3 camera, and it seems that some applications can be developed for it.

As far as I understand, the CameraRemoteAPI SDK can be used to develop Android or iOS applications. So is there a way to develop applications for the Sony camera?

I would like to develop a feature to be able to:

- set the timer (from 2s to 2min)
- select the number of shots (from 1 to 2000)
- select the time between shots.

There is an existing "intervalometer" application but it is very expensive.

Comment: OK sqince my question seems unclear: I am looking for information about developping application for Sony Camera RX100III.  When I looked into Sony support page I have been told to post on stack overflow.    I assume it is similar for all Sony camera.

Answer (score 0):

Camera Remote API SDK allows one to remotely control the supported Sony cameras including RX100M3 from any other device, by sending HTTP commands to the camera. The application you create can run from any 
platform Android, iOS , Windows, PC, etc. You will have to connect this device to the camera over WiFi.

To get more information, please download the SDK, which contains sample applications and API documentation.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team

Comment: Thank you, but my point is precisely not to make an external devices interface. Some features should have been embedded directely in the camera. Espescially on expert camera it is quite a shame that such feature are only available for expensive applications